# SQL Query where clause for multiple columns in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, exists

Having the below database:

[image: database]

Trying to execute below query:

```
select * 
from data_five_minutes 
where ((open in (select open 
                 from data_five_minutes 
                 where date_time = '2019-01-02 13:15:00')) > 
        (open in (select open 
                  from data_five_minutes 
                  where date_time = '2019-01-01 11:10:00')))
```

The above query gives me result give me 3 results but I was expecting 0!

What I try to fetch is:- get the row where the open of 02/01 13:15 > open of 01/01 11:10 having script_id same for both.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote is for, but often its because of using an image for the sample data.

Comment: the open of 02/01 13:15 is less than the open of 01/01 11:10.

Comment: You where condition doesn't really make sense to me. It boils down to `where one_boolean_expression > other_boolean_expression`  because `(open in (...))` yields either true or false, it does not return the value from the sub-query of the `IN` operator.

Comment: @forpas Yes, and that the reason it should give 0 result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I couldn't get you, if that is a bad type of executing query could you please help me with example related to my condition? I will try to create from there.

Comment: In case there are rows that satisfy the conditions, do you want 2 rows in the results?

Comment: @forpas Yes, two rows am sure those will be on different script_id

Comment: Why on different script_id? You say: *...having script_id same for both* in the question.

Comment: okay I miss understood your question, no I need only one row having date_time latest among them @forpas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT d1.* 
FROM data_five_minutes d1 
WHERE d1.date_time = '2019-01-02 13:15:00'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM data_five_minutes d2
    WHERE d2.date_time = '2019-01-01 11:10:00'
      AND d2.script_id = d1.script_id
      AND d2.open < d1.open
  );
```

Comment: This helped to fetch the data but the issue is when I ran the query in 900K+ rows it took 5 mins to fetch the data, and displayed 17 rows. there are only 250 script ids

Comment: @Kabomi the rows returned satisfy the conditions that you set, so I can't say anything about it. For the performance of the query you could create a composite index on date_time, script_id and open which would help.